# Differentiating $ e^{-2x}\sqrt{x^2 +1} $ and $ \sin^{2}3x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

After scouting around I've had no luck in finding answers to my question which is relatively simple for alot of you.

Before jumping straight to the question I 'd like to clarify that I'm not only looking for an answer, I'm asking *how* you got that answer, if you don't mind ofcourse!

---

Differentiate with respect to *x*

$$ e^{-2x}\sqrt{(x^{2} +1)} $$

---

If the first one is a bit too long to explain, feel free to answer and explain the following:
$$ \sin^{2}3x$$

---

Comment: Have you studied product and chain rules for differentiation?

Comment: Yes I have studied those a *while* back and am somewhat familiar with them. Personal issue is that I've had to jump from Intermediate level to Advanced level in the subject, thus what I learned is basically 'half' of what there is to know

Comment: OK, clear - because what you are facing here is a combination of those rules. Will give you hints. Ah - Did already wrote some down.

Comment: @NickyHekster Thanks alot nicky, appreciate it. I don't mind being thrown in the right direction and figuring out the rest for myself :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your answers:
$$-2e^{-2x}\sqrt{x^2+1} + e^{-2x}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
$$6\cos(3x)\sin(3x),$$ which last expression can be written as $3\sin(6x)$.

Comment: Thanks alot! Nicky do you mind if I ask *how* you've come to these conclusions or at least which formulas & rules you've used so that I can replicate these answers myself aswell?

Comment: Use the formulas Did gave! For example put $u=e^{-2x}$ and $v=\sqrt{x^2+1}$. However, the u´s and v´s are not the same throughout.

Comment: Aha alright, starting to make sense now bit by bit, thanks alot!

Comment: Before deciding my answers could I kindly ask what you meant exactly with the second part of your comment, "However, the u´s and v´s are not the same throughout"

Comment: "I don't mind being thrown in the right direction and figuring out the rest for myself" Why make this impossible?

Comment: @Juxhin - well if you use $(\sqrt{u})'=\frac{u'}{2\sqrt{u}}$, then you would put $u=x^2+1$, got it? Those formulas are written down with general $u$'s and $v$'s, so each time you choose the proper function $u$ or $v$ to apply those formulas.

Comment: @NickyHekster Yea it's slowly starting to make sense now. I'm trying to work it out all alone and whilst I'm getting answers very close to yours, they're not quite identical. I'll trying working out the problems using your formula, thanks

Comment: @Juxhin, if you still have problems - contact me off-line, and not here - see my profile for e-mail address

Comment: Click on my name above.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some useful rules. Consider some differentiable functions $u$ and $v$, then $$(uv)'=u'v+uv',\quad(\sqrt{u})'=\frac{u'}{2\sqrt{u}},\quad(\mathrm e^u)'=u'\mathrm e^u,\quad (u^2)'=2u'u.$$ These are special cases of the general fact that, if $F$ and $u$ are differentiable, then $$(F(u))'=u'\cdot F'(u).$$Can you solve the two examples in your question using these?

Comment: Thanks! These rules you've posted certainly do help. I can't answer the last part of your post just yet but I will go and expand on what you've just told me.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Did. I'm sorry I couldn't accept both answers as I wish I could've as the site doesn't allow so.

Comment: Did you **solve** the examples yourself? Well, I guess you cannot anymore now that full formulas are on the page... so let me rephrase: did you manage to **check** the explicit solutions?

Comment: I still haven't manage to work it from A to Z but these posts did clear most of the fog in my head. What's left to do is some more research and try to grasp the concept behind the answers

Comment: So, for all you know, the explicit formulas given to you for these two derivatives could be utter rubbish? (They are not.) The "concept behind the answers" is in my post, now what you need to do is to *do the computations yourself* (as they say, maths is not a spectator's sport...).

Comment: I'm not quite getting the point behind the comment, are you indirectly referring to the fact that I ticked his as the correct answer? Coming from another Stack community I know for a fact that most people value Votes > Ticked answer therefore it shouldn't be an issue. I understand exactly what you mean which is why I'm trying to replicate his answer using your answer(best of both worlds). He also clarified how he managed to get his answer by referring to your answer. So once again, I don't see what you're trying to tell me here

Comment: That I would never accept any answer before checking in depth what is in it. Since you accepted an answer with a *result* (rather than a *method*), the result better be correct for the answer to have any value at all, and how can you tell if you did not check yourself? I thought this was clear. But (i) this is just my point of view, (ii) I am only trying to *understand* what you are looking for on this site and you can legitimately answer that none of these considerations are my business, hence I should just shut up.

Comment: Which goes back to my point. (i) I am only allowed to select one answer, when I infact, wished to have both of the posts as the answer for this question as it incorporates both his and your post. (ii) Your answer has 4 upvotes(including mine) in comparison to his 1 upvote(which is only mine). Whilst his ANSWER(not method) was based on your answer as he clarified, I decided to give him the answered tag cause in the end of the day, his result was an answer and not the method to get the answer. Whilst I valued your post more, I found it appropriate to give it to him and that was my decision.

Comment: And now, what I fail to understand after all these excellent reasons is why you change... Whatever.

Comment: Sorry, must've had a mistake, I put the correct-answer back to the appropriate user. Thanks for informing me of the mistake